# Replacing an Element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify an element in jQuery programmatically, i.e. a number in *docID* increments up to a maximum number. I'm replacing text on a series of images on a page from *Download* to *View*. If I use `#ctl00_cphMainContent_dlProductList_ct100_ctl00_lnkProofDownload` instead of `docID` in the `$(docID).text(...)` part of the code, the text gets replaced correctly. When I use the `docID` variable in its place, it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

```
var max = 10;    
var count = 100;

var s1 = "#ctl00_cphMainContent_dlProductList_ct";
var s2 = "_ctl00_lnkProofDownload";
var docID = "";

for (i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
  docID = s1.concat (count++, s2);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(docID).text(function(i, oldText) {
      return oldText === 'Download' ? 'View' : oldText;
    });
  });
}
```

This is the HTML code that is being modified. The word Download is replaced by View.

```
<a id="ctl00_cphMainContent_dlProductList_ctl00_ctl00_lnkProofDownload"
   href="../../../Controls/StaticDocProof.ashx?qs=op/5WlcUxeg849UT973Mwf0ZnNcMLfe3JYAe7EnJORsdyETYV1vcKaj0ROc2VrN5fXfYjO2MM6BUYXzX2UKmog=="
   >Download</a>
```

Comment: can you share the generated html as well?

Comment: There's a lot wrong here.. for one, your doc.ready function is in a loop...

Comment: prepare a fiddle, please

Comment: I'm not sure what @RickHitchcock is saying there, but you could have more going on in your HTML, showing a full page (or fiddle as dolek suggested) could be helpful

Comment: @vol7ron, ha, I hope I explained it better in my answer.

Comment: Rick, yes I didn't notice the `1` vs `l`, in my font they look very similar — d'oh

Comment: in the for loop can u just try writing the value of docID into the console and give us the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have done a couple things incorrectly in your code, including using a 1 instead of an l. If it was supposed to be a 100 instead of a l00, something more like this would work:

```
jQuery(function () {
    var max = 10,
        count = 100,
        s1 = 'ctl00_cphMainContent_dlProductList_ct',
        s2 = '_ctl00_lnkProofDownload',
        docID;

    for (var i = count; i <= count + max; i++) {
        docID = s1 + i + s2;
        jQuery('#' + docID).text(function (idx, oldText) {
            return oldText === 'Download' ? 'View' : oldText;
        });
    }
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ochguL2d/

Otherwise, let us know if it is supposed to be l00 for a different answer.

Comment: Thanks Dufmaster33. Your solutions works. I apologize for my poorly worded question, the error (ctl) in the HTML, and my limited understanding of jQuery (which I'm still learning). You saved me quite a bit of time on another solution that I would have used instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` element has this in the middle (note two "els"):

```
ctl00_ctl00
```

… but your `docID` has this in the middle (note a "one and an el"):

```
ct100_ctl00
```

Fix your HTML, and your code works as-is:  http://jsfiddle.net/5c7hwyts/

However, that's an odd way to write jQuery.

Here's a different approach:

```
$('a').text(function(i, oldText) {
  var num= parseInt(this.id.split('ctl00_cphMainContent_dlProductList_ct')[1]);
  if(num>=100 && num<110) {
    return oldText === 'Download' ? 'View' : oldText;    
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9z2cj6zs/)

Comment: Nice catch — `L` is different from `1`

Answer (score 0):

The element IDs your are trying to match in your code are not the ones in the DOM.

```
// This is what you want to match
var domID = "#ctl00_cphMainContent_dlProductList_ct100_ctl00_lnkProofDownload"
                                                         ^ that is an L
// this what your code is trying to match in its first iteration    
var docID = "#ctl00_cphMainContent_dlProductList_ct10_ctl00_lnkProofDownload";"
                                                        ^ that is a 1 (one)
```

Also, your code's `max` variable needs to be a two char numeric string with leading zeros starting at zero, not an integer starting at 10.

Personally, I would just:

```
// On DomReady...
$(document).ready(function() {
    //  loop through all anchors that have "lnkProofDownload" in their ID attribute
    $('a[id*="lnkProofDownload"]').each(function() {
        // and if the text is set to "Download", change it to "View"
        if ($(this).text() == "Download") {
            $(this).text("View");
        }
    });
});
```